# Aligning Bootstrap Radio Buttons with text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome, vertical-alignment

I am trying to get my radio buttons to align but I am having difficulty doing this. What I am trying to do is have the buttons align with an indentation because I am going to display a caret if the option has been selected. I also want the text to come up just a bit because it's not inline with the actual radio button.

```css
input[type=radio] {
  z-index: 3;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}
label {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.question-label {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <span class="button"><input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" value="20"></span>
    <span class="question-label">True</span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <span><i class="fa fa-caret-right fa-2x correct-answer" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    <span class="button"><input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" value="20"></span>
    <span class="question-label">False</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Here is what it looks like right now.

[image]

Comment: it looks good for me

Comment: Please provide js fiddle

Comment: Looks fine in the snippet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did a few things to your code:

1. Align the items inside the `label` using `inline-block`s:

   ```
   .radio label > span {
       display: inline-block;
       vertical-align: middle;
   }
   ```

   This is better than positioning using `px`.
2. Now add the caret icon to both `radio` so that the horizontal alignment will be automatically done (and you can contextually show the green caret). To make that work apply these:

   ```
   .correct-answer {
     color: green;
   }
   .wrong-answer {
     opacity: 0;
   }
   ```

Let me know your feedback. Thanks!

```css
input[type=radio] {
  z-index: 3;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}
label {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.question-label {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.radio label > span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.correct-answer {
  color: green;
}
.wrong-answer {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <span><i class="fa fa-caret-right fa-2x wrong-answer" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    <span class="button"><input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" value="20"></span>
    <span class="question-label">True</span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <span><i class="fa fa-caret-right fa-2x correct-answer" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    <span class="button"><input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" value="20"></span>
    <span class="question-label">False</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `.radio span.button{ position:relative; top: 4px;}`
and `input[type=radio] {margin:0;}` to your css

```css
input[type=radio] {
  z-index: 3;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  margin:0;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}
label {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.question-label {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.radio span.button{ position:relative; top: 4px;}
```

```html
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <span class="button"><input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" value="20"></span>
    <span class="question-label">True</span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <span><i class="fa fa-caret-right fa-2x correct-answer" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    <span class="button"><input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" value="20"></span>
    <span class="question-label">False</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
input[type=radio] {
  z-index: 3;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}
label {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.question-label {
  margin-left: 5px;
  position:absolute;
  margin-top:3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <span class="button"><input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" value="20"></span>
    <span class="question-label">True</span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <span><i class="fa fa-caret-right fa-2x correct-answer" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    <span class="button"><input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" value="20"></span>
    <span class="question-label">False</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i did some changes in your dom as you want caret before radio button.you can set visibility of those caret when you dont want it to be visible as changing visibility will still occupy space  on screen as compare to display:none which will affect indentation of radio

```
<div class="radio">
   <span><i class="fa fa-caret-right fa-2x correct-answer" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
   <label>
   <span class="button"><input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" value="20"></span>
   <span class="question-label">True</span>
   </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
   <span><i class="fa fa-caret-right fa-2x correct-answer" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
   <label>
   <span class="button"><input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" value="20"></span>
   <span class="question-label">False</span>
   </label>
</div>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p45j3bmf/1/)